# Is there an ftp management tool that is not based on PHP?

Tags: 12.04, ftp

I am looking for an ftp tool GUI that makes it easier for some low-tech users to add/delete FTP accounts restricted to certain folders.

Currently I am doing this by hand in my `vsftpd.conf` but I am not too fussed about the one FTP server over another.

I am trying to *not* install PHP though and cpanel(apart from being PHP based) and the like seem to be too hard to use for low techies...

Anyone can point me to a nice app with a modern web interface??

I mentioned PHP specifically because every tool I found so far seems to be build in PHP and I rather not install PHP just for this. I got python, perl and node installed...

Comment: What are the reasons for avoiding PHP?  This could be relevant in determining what other things might also be unsuitable.

Comment: I just don't want to install something I don't need opening up one more potential surface that could have security issues.

Comment: This will be the case with anything that uses a web interface, or for that matter any other protocol - the configuration interface will happen over a communications channel open to the world - opening up another potential attack surface.  For the paranoid you can run on a non-standard port, run it over TLS, chroot your server, or other things - or accept that there are many experts who study the security of common web servers like Apache for weaknesses.

Comment: Mate, this is not to piss on your parade or anything. I am looking for something that is either build into ubuntu(perl) or I got installed already(node). Don't worry about it if you don't know any. Neither do I ;)

Comment: I was trying to get a sense of what you were asking for, because it wasn't clear why PHP was excluded.  Your edit to the question is good.